# ADT function keeps returning null and i have NO clue why

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

my insert function keeps returning null and printing out "not found" for some reason. I feel like it has something to do with the fact that head is null and is not assigned to be a new Node.. but i can't do this in findKey because it is a private class:

```
// findKey()
// returns a reference to the Node at key in the LinkedList; otherwise returns null
private Node findKey(String key){
    Node N = head;
 while(N != null){
    N = N.next;
    if(N.key.equals(key) && N.key != null){
      return N;
  }
    }
    return null;

}
public String lookup(String key){
 if(findKey(key) == null){
     System.out.println("not found");
     return null;
  }else{
  Node N = findKey(key);
  return N.value;
  }
}

public void insert(String key, String value)
  throws KeyCollisionException{

  if(lookup(key)!= null ){
     throw new KeyCollisionException(
        "cannot create duplicate key");
  }
  if(head == null){
    head = new Node(key,value);
    return;
    }else{
    Node iter = head;
    while(iter.next != null){
    iter = iter.next;
    }
    Node N = new Node(key,value);
    iter.next = N;
    numItems++;
    }
```

}

Comment: Can't you just add a check in `insert()` to see if head is null? If it is then just automatically add the current key/value?

Comment: i think that's what i tried to do in the lines :if(head == null){
    head = new Node(key,value);
    return;

Comment: You did, but only _after_ calling `lookup()` which then calls `findKey()` which then uses `head` (which could be null) as the value for N.

Comment: ohh okay. i moved my check to before the call to lookup()

Comment: And is that working out for you? If so, I will post it as an answer.

Comment: i think it was a combination of that and also of what SoleZero said, to use this.key and this.value. Thank you guys SO much!!

Comment: No problem. I have posted an answer with the combined solutions. Please review it and upvote/accept if it contains everything.

Answer (score 0):

You're moving to the next node too early in `findKey` which means you will never check the `head` node to see if it contains the required key and that you will get NullPointerExceptions if the key isn't found.

Just move the `N = N.next;` line down a bit. Also, swap the order of checks around in the `if` statement (although your `Node` constructor should prevent null keys anyway):

```
private Node findKey(String key){
    Node N = head;

    while(N != null){
        if(N.key != null && N.key.equals(key)){
            return N;
        }
        N = N.next;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: i tried that but it still prints out "not found" :(

Answer (score 0):

You should use the *this* keyword in your constructor:

```
Node(String key, String value){
    while(key != null && value !=null){
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
    next = null;
}
```

And "while" is not necessary. Using "if" is better.

Comment: this worked kind of! now it prints out:
not found
not found
.
.
not found
1 2a 3b 4c 5d 6e 7f 8g

Comment: Another problem in your code is that inside findKey(), **head** is never checked against. You should do "N = N.next" after comparing the key, like this:  while(N != null){
    if(N.key.equals(key) && N.key != null){
      return N;
  }     N = N.next; }

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems which could be leading to your issues. First off, because you use the same variable names for your class's fields and the constructor's parameters, you should be using the `this` keyword to distinguish between the 2. Also, you should change the while loop to an if statement because you are not looping through anything. If the if statement should fail, you should set some default values or throw a `NullPointerException`. Change:

```
String key;
String value;

Node(String key, String value) {
    while(key != null && value != null) {
        key = key;
        value = value;
    }
}
```

to

```
String key;
String value;

Node(String key, String value) {
    if(key != null && value != null) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
    else {
        throw new NullPointerException("Initial values cannot be null");
    }
}
```

Secondly, you have

```
if(lookup(key) != null ) {
    throw new KeyCollisionException("cannot create duplicate key");
}
if(head == null) {
    head = new Node(key,value);
    ...
}
```

It is good that you set `head` to a new node if it is null, but you are doing it *after* making a method call which will result in `head` being referenced inside of `findKey()`. You should switch the order of these operations to prevent your `NullPointerException`.

```
if(head == null) {
    head = new Node(key,value);
    ...
}
if(lookup(key) != null ) {
    throw new KeyCollisionException("cannot create duplicate key");
}
```